# SQL Request from several tables in Yii2

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2

I have 2 tables.
and $id variable with id of A table

```
$A_data= A::find()
    ->where(['id' => $id])
    ->one();
$B_data= B::find()
    ->where(['id' => $A_data->B_id])
    ->one();
echo $B_data->name;
```

This code takes id and gets line from A table, then taking B_id from that line gets line from B table.
Then I print out data from B table.

How can I do this with one single request ? not asking tables for data one after another ?

Comment: Did you read this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#working-with-relational-data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the following relation in your `A` model, e.g. :

```
public function getB()
{
    return $this->hasOne(B::className(), ['id' => 'B_id']);
}
```

And your code could be :

```
$A_data = A::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
echo $A_data->B->name;
```

PS: there will be two sql requests for this (lazy or eager).